# Question about galois imaginary and modular arithmetic

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime of type $3\space mod \space 4$.
Then there is no solution $x^2 = -1 \space mod \space p$.
Therefore we can define the so-called Galois imaginary $i$.
( $i^2 = -1 \space mod \space p$ )

Now by adding this galois imaginary , we consider $a + bi \space mod \space p$.

Computing with this $a+bi$ is similar to usual modular arithmetic.
We know for instance how to simplify $(a+bi)^c$ , multiply , add and substract.

However , does it make sense to consider

$(a + bi)^{c + di} \space mod \space p$

where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $d$ is nonzero ?

Comment: You're simply forming a quadratic extension of some field of characteristic $\;p=3\pmod 4\;$ , say of $\;\Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc thats just describing mod p. 
This does not help to understand $(a+b i)^{c+di}$.

Comment: Ok, Read the following for some interesting, and very similar, views: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11781/complex-powers-in-finite-fields

Comment: Exponentiation with $\Bbb N$-powers (natural numbers) is always defined, for reasons that are almost more logical than mathematical. But to define exponentiation by $i$ requires an effort: it’s not even possible for a rational base, not in any obvious way, anyway. I think that this is a question that you should spend some computational and experimental time on. Pencil and paper, I mean.