# Solutions $n^2 = -1 \mod (p_n-1)$

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Consider the equation $n^2 = -1 \mod (p_n-1)(*)$ where $p_n > n$ and $f(n) = p_n$ is the largest prime that satisfies the equation.

$f(n)$ gives $p_n$ assuming there is a solution to the equation $(*)$, otherwise it gives $0$.

$g(n)$ is the $n$th value for which $f(g(n))$ gives a nonzero value.

Im curious about the sequences $g(n)$ and $p_{g(n)}$.

For instance what is their growth rate ?

Comment: I am just curious, what context does this come from?

Comment: @flawr http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114950/question-about-galois-imaginary-and-modular-arithmetic
and
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11781/complex-powers-in-finite-fields